# How can I make divs dynamically fill up fixed-size container and shrink and/or expand depending on number of divs in the container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Introduction** 
I am currently learning web development and I am trying to make some sort of etch-a-sketch thing and it should pop out a grid with up to 100 square cells per side BUT no matter what number of cells per side the grid itself should be using the same amount of space, so for example if the total space it could use was 1000px then the grid, no matter how many cells it has, will use 1000px, no more or no less. My problem is that I'm not sure what I should do to make the grid do this.

**Problem context** 
For starters, for my purposes I can only generate the grid itself via Javascript. In the Javascript I use a doubly-nested for loop where after each iteration in the first loop, a new "grid-row" div will be created and then the second for loop will populate that grid row with "square" divs, so if I set the number as 5 per-side, it will create a grid-row and populate that row with 5 square divs 5 times.

**My problem** 
The whole grid itself is wrapped in a "grid-container" div with a fixed size. **I would like to make it so the grid will always fill up the size of the grid container but not exceed the container itself. In other words, I would like to find a way to make the square and/or grid-row divs be able to shrink or grow depending on the number of them inside the grid-container so as to not have the overall grid exceed the size of the grid-container itself but still fill up the available space in the container.**

So far I have played around with various CSS properties suggestions that I found from Google searches such as setting height and width of either the "square" or "grid-row" divs (or both of them at the same time) to 100%, playing around with the max widths and heights, as well as their mins, and playing around with the "overflow" and object-fit properties. I'm not sure if there was a solution for my problem in Javascript and if there was I haven't found one in my myriad Google searches.

Here's my code snippet, I'd appreciate any help:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".grid-container");

for (let x = 0; x < 6; x++) { 
/* Both the "x" and "y" variables are set to arbitrary values (up to 100). The "x" variable here represents how many total "rows" the grid will create. The following "y" variable represents how many square divs will populate each row, so both of these numbers should be the same to make a square grid.*/
    let newRow = document.createElement('div');
    newRow.classList = `grid-row`;
    container.appendChild(newRow);
    for (let y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
        let square = document.createElement('div');
        square.classList = `square`;
        newRow.appendChild(square);
        }
}

const gridCells = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

gridCells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        cell.classList.add("hov-square");
    });
});
```

```css
/*This is the current state of the CSS file that I left on prior to posting this question. I set the width and height of the "square" divs to 10px each to make the grid visible and to give an idea of what the grid may look like, but my goal is for the grid (the grid-rows and the square divs inside of it) to be able to fill up the "grid-container" div that wraps the grid itself and resize itself depending on how many square cells are in the grid but never exceed the size of the grid-container itself.*/

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.grid-container {
    margin-top: 10%;
    display: flex;
    width: 750px;
    height: 750px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: visible;
}

.grid-row {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.square {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed white;
    
}

.hov-square {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I grabbed the width of the grid-container, then divided that by the number of columns to get the width/height of each cell.

Then I used javascript to set the width and height to that size.

I got rid of the grid-row CSS. Also, you don't need to loop through the cells to add hover class. Just use **.square:hover** in CSS and it will automatically apply it to the matching cells.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".grid-container");

let squares = 100;
let _parent_width = getComputedStyle(container).width;
let sq_size = Math.floor(_parent_width.replace("px","") / squares) - 2;

for (let x = 0; x < squares; x++) { 
    let newRow = document.createElement('div');
    newRow.classList = `grid-row`;
    container.appendChild(newRow);
    for (let y = 0; y < squares; y++) {
        let square = document.createElement('div');
        square.classList.add("square");
        square.style.width = sq_size + "px";
        square.style.height = sq_size + "px";
        newRow.appendChild(square);
        }
}

const gridCells = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

gridCells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        cell.classList.add("hov-square");
    });
});
```

```css
/*This is the current state of the CSS file that I left on prior to posting this question. I set the width and height of the "square" divs to 10px each to make the grid visible and to give an idea of what the grid may look like, but my goal is for the grid (the grid-rows and the square divs inside of it) to be able to fill up the "grid-container" div that wraps the grid itself and resize itself depending on how many square cells are in the grid but never exceed the size of the grid-container itself.*/

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.grid-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: visible;
}

.square {
    border: 1px dashed white;
    
}

.hov-square{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">c</div>
```

Comment: I like the approach with the Javascript, I haven't thought of doing it that way, but unfortunately when I run this code the grid seems to not respect the grid-container size, especially when I let squares = 100 which I want it to be able to generate a 100x100 grid of. Also, (this is unrelated to the problem) I wanted the hover effect after mouseover on the cells to stay, which is why I didn't use the hover property in CSS.

Comment: @ronnie34mu, I updated my answer. Now instead of round, I use floor to get the lowest and I subtract 2 to cover the size of the border.

Comment: It still exceeds the grid-container size for me, but I think it's a fault of mine for maybe not explaining the problem I have correctly, here's my problem reworded: I would like to make it so the grid will always fill up the size of the grid container but not exceed the container itself. In other words, I would like to find a way to make the square and/or grid-row divs be able to shrink or grow depending on the number of them inside the grid-container so as to not have the overall grid exceed the size of the grid-container itself but still fill up the available space in the container.

Comment: After playing around with your code in jsfiddle, I'm not sure if it's just a problem with my viewport or something else on my end, because it seems to respect the size in jsfiddle.

Comment: When I run it on my own browser the grid seems to max out on my viewport size but this doesn't happen in the jsfiddle